# How to do something in QtWidgets.QDialog close event

Tags: python, pyqt5, qdialog

i am using `self.sub_dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog(self)`
I want to clear a QLineEdite when the sub_dialog closing event. How to do?

Comment: That depends, as there are different ways of "closing" a QDialog: when the user accepts/rejects the dialog by pressing a button like Ok or Cancel, or pressing the Esc key, or tries to close by clicking on the X button of the window. What behavior are you looking for?

Comment: inherit from `QtWidgets.QDialog` and override `closeEvent`

Comment: @musicamante  by clicking on the X button of the window and there are no accepts/rejects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.line_main = QLineEdit("Line", self)

        self.resize(800,500)
        self.show()

        self.dialog = QDialog(self)
        self.line = QLineEdit("Line", self.dialog)
        self.dialog.resize(400,300)
        self.dialog.closeEvent = self.line_clear
        self.dialog.exec_()

        self.resize(800,500)
        self.show()

    def line_clear(self, event):
        if self.line.text() != "":
            self.line_main.clear()
            self.line.clear()
            print("Success")


app = QApplication([])
window = main()
app.exec()
```

Comment: it is clearing the QLineEdit text but not closing the sub window at that time. And I have main Event to main Window also.

Comment: I mean, to close sub window, need to press x button twice. can we fix it to once.

Comment: i changed try that

Comment: or you can delete this row  ==》 if self.line.text() != "":